# Upgrading to 10.10 has made the terminal go crazy

Tags: 10.10, xorg, command-line, fonts, emacs

I asked this question on the [unix/linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/weird-stuff-going-on-in-terminal-and-emacs-since-upgrade-to-ubuntu-10-10) and someone suggested I try my luck here.
The problem is this: since upgrading to 10.10, the terminal has gone a little funny. Here's a picture of the problem:

[image: Weird stuff]

The problem affects `xterm` but not `gnome-terminal`. I also get similar weird artefacts in emacs (though only after I alt-tab away and back to the window for the first time).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> or moving the window or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>ing away and then back again makes the lines disappear.

Someone asked about the problem on [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1597277) with no luck so far.

Comment: This is not an upgrade problem. I'm seeing it in a new 10.10 installation.

Comment: While moving the window gives a temporary clear view, resizing the window makes it to behave normal during the session. Its obviously a bug. A friend asked about it [here](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1597277)

Comment: Please report a bug in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xterm/)

Comment: I don't know where to report the bug. It's not just xterm: it happens in emacs too, but not in gnome-shell, so I don't know where the bug should be reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a bug. You should report the bug [against xterm](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xterm/) in Launchpad.

You can also mark as affecting emac (using the "Also Affects Distribution" link once you have reported the bug). The maintainers of those two applications can then comment and potentially reassign the bug to other packages.

**Update**: the issue has been reported, take a look at Launchpad [Bug #663469](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xterm/+bug/663469).

Comment: But I don't think it's a bug with xterm. If it's affecting other stuff, I expect it's a problem with xorg or something. I'll open a bug report anyway...

Comment: I don't think that matters, they can reassign it. You can always mark it as 'affecting xorg' and see what the xorg guys say.

Comment: The bug is an xorg bug and has apparently been fixed. https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/635258